Shadowing the chapter name
I want my chaptername to be shadowed. But when I did like this, only the chapter number is shadowed. Can someone help me to fix this?
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,yhmath,mathrsfs,fontawesome}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-tab}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows,calc,intersections,angles,quotes,patterns,snakes,positioning}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.4}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm] {geometry}
\usepackage[hidelinks,unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{currfile}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\colorlet{tcbcol@back}{tcbcolback}
\colorlet{tcbcol@frame}{tcbcolframe}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\newcommand{\shadowedtext}[2][black!25!white]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(T.base)]
        \node[scale=1, yshift=-0.5mm, xshift=0.5mm, text=#1] (S) {\MakeUppercase{#2}};
        \node[scale=1] (T) {\MakeUppercase{#2}};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}   
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-10pt}{20pt}
\titleformat{\chapter}
{\Large\bfseries\color{black}}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw[double,thick,line join=round,red!70!black] (0,0) node[above right]{\bfseries\fontsize{24}{1pt}\color{red!70!black}\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont \shadowedtext{CHAPTER \thechapter\ }}--(5,0)--(5.6,1.2)--(\textwidth,1.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
{8em}
{\fontsize{24pt}{1pt}\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont\color{red!70!black}\MakeUppercase}
\begin{document}
\newpage
\chapter{CHAPTER NAME}
\end{document}


Here is the result that I got


As mentioned in the titlesec documentation on page 4, the \titleformat command has five mandatory arguments, of which the last one is before-code. This argument is described as follows:

⟨before-code⟩ is the code preceding the title body. The very last command can take an argument, which is the title text.

Currently your before-code is:
\fontsize{24pt}{1pt}\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont\color{red!70!black}\MakeUppercase

The last command is \MakeUppercase. This means that this command will be applied to the title text (here "CHAPTER NAME"), which means this argument will be put into upper case (i.e., the code will do \MakeUppercase{CHAPTER NAME}). Instead of calling \MakeUppercase, you should call \shadowedtext here. The command definition for \shadowedtext also contains \MakeUppercase, so the uppercasing is covered (besides the example chapter being already provided in upper case in the MWE).
Code:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,yhmath,mathrsfs,fontawesome}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-tab}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows,calc,intersections,angles,quotes,patterns,snakes,positioning}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.4}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm] {geometry}
\usepackage[hidelinks,unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{currfile}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\colorlet{tcbcol@back}{tcbcolback}
\colorlet{tcbcol@frame}{tcbcolframe}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\newcommand{\shadowedtext}[2][black!25!white]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(T.base)]
        \node[scale=1, yshift=-0.5mm, xshift=0.5mm, text=#1] (S) {\MakeUppercase{#2}};
        \node[scale=1] (T) {\MakeUppercase{#2}};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}   
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-10pt}{20pt}
\titleformat{\chapter}
{\Large\bfseries\color{black}}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw[double,thick,line join=round,red!70!black] (0,0) node[above right]{\bfseries\fontsize{24}{1pt}\color{red!70!black}\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont \shadowedtext{CHAPTER \thechapter\ }}--(5,0)--(5.6,1.2)--(\textwidth,1.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
{8em}
{\fontsize{24pt}{1pt}\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont\color{red!70!black}\shadowedtext}
\begin{document}
\newpage
\chapter{chapter name}
\end{document}

Result:


Many thanks. It works perfectly.

I have another problem. If my chapter name is longer, it will be out of page. Is there any way to solve that problem?

Well, you can make the chapter name shorter.... otherwise how would you like to display it?

You mean like \titleformat{\chapter}[display] ?

No, I mean, what should happen when the name is too long? Cut it off? Make it smaller? Go on the next line?

Yes go on the next line

@HưngTrần in the definition of \shadowedtext you could put \node[scale=1, yshift=-0.5mm, xshift=0.5mm, text=#1] (S) {\parbox{0.6\textwidth}{\MakeUppercase{#2}}};         \node[scale=1] (T) {\parbox{0.6\textwidth}{\MakeUppercase{#2}}}; instead of the two nodes that are there now, but it doesn't look great. Using shorter titles or using a design that is better suited for multi-line titles would be better,

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
